# Is there a way to have my WCF settings set programatically?

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration

I need to be able to store the XML of my web.config serviceModel element in a database, and have my application read it at startup.  Is there a way to do this by just changing my startup code to "override" the serviceModel element in the .config file?  I see there is an answer to another question about doing this for the appSettings section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158783/is-there-a-way-to-override-configurationmanager-appsettings).

How can I do this for serviceModel?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you can load a service model configuration from any config file you wish :-) No problem at all.

If you need to do this frequently, you might want to consider creating your own custom ServiceHost class. On how to do this, see this excellent [blog post](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/11/26/reading-wcf-configuration-from-a-custom-location.aspx), or this one in particular for [hosting a service inside IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/22/custom-service-config-file-for-a-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx).

Marc