# Override WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"] dynamically during execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, overriding

I have a code like that:

```
// can't make any changes at that class
class MyClass
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // some code ...

        var someVar = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"];

        // some code ...
    }
}
```

I can't change that code, but I need that WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"] return different values depending on some external conditions (for example, depending on user role). So I'm looking for some way to override accessing to that property. In that override method I would check user role and 
return appropriate value.

Is there any way to do that?

I found that question: [Is there a way to override ConfigurationManager.AppSettings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158783/is-there-a-way-to-override-configurationmanager-appsettings) but it seems that it's not suitable for me, because here value of WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"] set once when application starts. And I need to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, in order to simplify the testing and mocking, I tend to use customized object for all the common classes, like Request, Session and ConfigManager, referenced through interfaces.
You basically don't need to realize classes from scratch obviously, so your implementation can be a wrapper which is actually using the .net class under the hood, but which gives also the chance to insert some custom logic in the middle, like in your case.

Therefore, you can create a wrapper of the webconfigurationManager, with a method like GetAppConfig(key) containing your own logic.
Playing with the concept of dependency injection is then easy enough having this class available wherever you need it.

Therefore to make a simple example:

```
//this will be injected
public MyControllerCtor(IConfig cfg)

public interface IConfig
{
   string GetAppConfig(string key);
}

public class myConfig:IConfig
{
   public string GetAppConfig(string key)
   {    
      //your logic
      var someVar = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"];
      //your logic

      return yourCustomAppSetting;
   }
}
```

Big advantage of this approach is that if you wanted to store your config in a database or a service, and change your code, you simply need to change your interface implementation and the inject the new instance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do some logic after retrieving the value from the web.config. If the logic modifies the value itself, you could always store a format string in the web.config instead.

Here's an example using a connection string setting. I'm using a format string to populate the server name at runtime:

```
<add name="sqlconnection" connectionString="Server={0}\SQLEXPRESS;Database=xxx;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
```

And then I'm using this logic:

```
string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection"].ConnectionString;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(connect))
{
    //check to see if the connection string needs to be set at runtime
    if (connect.Contains("{0}"))
        connect = String.Format(connect, HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName);
}

return connect;
```

**EDIT:** If you can't edit the class directly, I would consider creating a partial class to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's interesting solution and I'll take note of it. But it's not suitable for me in that case, because I have a class and method within it, which contains that code, and I can't change anything at that class. But thanks again.

Comment: Doesn't mean he can't use this elsewhere.

Comment: Added a suggestion that might help you get around the fact that you can't edit the class directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the code that is reading the AppSettings, then there is no way to do what you want. WebConfigurationManager is not pluggable or replacable externally.

You'll have to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not.

If you can't change the class, then you can't change the behavior. There's no general reason why Microsoft would have placed an "override" capability inside of WebApplicationManager. Usually, one is expected to be able to change ones class, or else to design it properly so that it can be overridden the right way.

Answer (score -1):

If you make direct changes to Web.config they will be effective only during the next request, and as I understand, this is not the desired effect.

You can not directly affect WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"], and that's the desired behavior, as the AppSettings as configurations are something static.

To achieve an effect close to what you desire, I'd suggest you to use the HttpContext.Current.Items collection, in which you will initialize in Application_BeginRequest to a certain value if conditions are met or default to WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"] otherwise.
Than, instead of accessing WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"] you will be accessing HttpContext.Current.Items["SomeProperty"].

Comment: Thank you for reply. But the problem is that I already have code, that uses WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"] and I can't change it. So I need somehow catch all calls to WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeProperty"] and override them

Comment: I am afraid this will not be possible. Find and replace would be your best friend... and for future, it's always good to encapsulate such behavior into a function, so that whenever you make changes, you have to change it only in one place.