# Detect reload of appSettings in ConfigurationManager

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, configuration

we're configuring parts of an application at runtime:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"] = "someValue";
```

This code is called on init of an http module, so it's very early and it works fine - almost.
The reason is for an framework, where we (guys providing the framework) want to avoid that the users of the framework (some other dev's in our company)

- forget adding this setting to the web.config or
- add wrong values in their specific web.configs

Now, under some circumstances (that is, i.e. high memory pressure) the ConfigurationManager obviously drops the `NameValueCollection` for the appSettings and reloads the values from the file, so that the key/value we added by code is lost.

This happens sometimes after the web application runs fine for several hours. It is *very* rare and happens only when the web application seems to be under heavy load.

Now the question is:

Is there a way to

- prevent the Configuration manager dropping and reloading the appSettings (this would include calls to `RefreshSection`) or
- detect when the configuration manager drops its appSettings section, so that we can react and add the key again or
- is there any other means to put a value into appSettings by code and persisting it until the application restarts the next time, without actually changing the web.config file?

Update: Determined the reason why the values are dropped (memory pressure)

Comment: Have you thought about defining and using your own configuration section (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CustomConfigurationSectio.aspx) ? I suppose you would be more in control.

Comment: The problem is that this is to configure a set of third party asp.net components, which don't use a custom configuration section.

Comment: You can redefine the appSettings section handler in machine.config. Is this reasonable for you?

Comment: +1 for that idea, but there are things we would have to check (with administration etc.), but I have a strong doubt we can get that rolled out on every required production server.

Comment: Have you considered writing your values directly into the appConfig section using the ConfigurationManager class? This would keep them around, though it might (probably) cause an app reload because you're touching the config file.

Comment: That is not an option. Out of security reasons the web application must not have the slightest permission to write even a single bit.

Comment: Here's a kludge that may or may not be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158783

Comment: Kevin, you just rescued me :) That's great and working. Thank you :) If you post this as an answer I'd be happy to give you the bounty.

Comment: I'm going to throw a bomb: you're wasting your time, if you're doing all that for reasons that you stated. Throw an exception! State that the app is misconfigured. It's perfectly acceptable. Why is something even in config, if you're simply going to hard-code it. Unless I'm not seeing something here, I'm pretty sure that your reasons are totally wrong. Cause, whatever you do within your obfuscated library, the framework-user developer can also do and overwrite your config change. It's just unnecessary clutter, IMO.

Comment: That would mean to check that value in each and every web request. If we do that, we could simply check, if the value is not there or is wrong, change it again. But these checks on every single request costs performance, which is not acceptable in a high-availability environment, where we already do massive micro-optimization because that pays in saving a lot of money in hardware. The solution of kevin is perfect for us and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that Kevin P. Rice offered in his comment is great for this problem.
It's answered here: [Is there a way to override ConfigurationManager.AppSettings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158783)

Answer (score 0):

Since these AppSettings are for a custom component (yours) and you apparently are able to provide reasonable defaults whenever you need to then the sensible option to me is not to worry about if it gets dumped and reloaded. Instead create a configuration wrapper class (you may even already have one), use this to wrap any calls to AppSettings, if the key is defined then return the value, otherwise return your default.

No need to worry about Prevention/Detection/Reaction this way.

Comment: The third party component directly accesses AppSettings[], I can't change it to use a wrapper. That's the reason why we inject our setting there in the first place.

Comment: @SebastianP.R.Gingter - Are you able to reproduce your issue on demand by creating your own load?

Comment: More or less reliable. I wrote a small tool that allocates memory on demand, so I can create memory pressure. When I allocate enough, the web application will eventually drop the cache and the setting is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a reason that these manually-added settings shouldn't ever be part of the configuration, why not just save them?

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"] = "someValue";
ConfigurationManager.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

This way even if hashtable is dropped, values will be re-loaded from the config file.

Comment: As already mentioned in some other comments here, for security settings the application is not allowed to write at all, especially not in its own application root.